# sed command to replace string beginning with spaces and "ssid" but not "scan_ssid"?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace a string in a config file that may have some extra spaces at the beginning without picking up another line.

```
network={
  scan_ssid=1
  ssid="My SSID can contain *any* char!"
  psk="6876876868"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

The problem is the leading space(s) and the `scan_ssid` are conflicting any expression I try. I need to match any number of spaces but not any chars.

Everything I've tried changes both `ssid` and `scan_ssid`

Comment: What is the command you already have. Post it eventhough if it did not solve your problem

Comment: What do you want to change the `ssid` to? Or you want to replace the entire line?

Comment: I have a hundred commands. They're no use to man nor beast. Thanks for you responses though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this simple `sed` a try:

```
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*ssid=.*/replacement/' data
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been bashing my fingers on the keyboard for 2 hours with that.